# Oracle case statement with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the SQL I have now:

```
SELECT i.busn_id,
       i.area_name,
       i.date,
       i.area_status,
       i.last_reason_id,
       last_reason.reason_description,
       i.first_reason_id,
       first_reason.reason_description
  FROM busn_info i
       JOIN busn_reason first_reason
         ON( i.first_reason_id = first_reason.reason_id )
       JOIN busn_reason last_reason
         ON( i.last_reason_id = last_reason.reason_id )
```

This SQL works great, but it only returns rows that have a LAST_REASON_ID and FIRST_REASON_ID. I want to include rows that may only have a LAST_REASON_ID or only a FIRST_REASON_ID but NOT rows that don't have either.

I think there needs to be some kind of logical process built into it. Would a case stmt make sense? I've looked at examples on Stackoverflow and google, but I need a bit more guidance.

Please let me know if I need to include anymore data to explain what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified, self-contained examples (DDL to create the table, DML to populate a few rows to reproduce the issue, and expected output) are always helpful. The query you posted will return 1 row for every row in the `busn_info` table.  If you only want rows where `first_reason_id is not null` or where `last_reason_id is not null`, just add that to the `where` clause

```
 Select BUSN_ID,
        AREA_NAME,
        DATE,
        AREA_STATUS,
        a.last_reason_id,
        (Select B.REASON_description
           FROM BUSN_REASONS B
          WHERE A.LAST_REASON_ID=B.REASON_ID), 
        a.first_reason_id,
        (Select B.REASON_description
           FROM BUSN_REASONS B
          WHERE A.FIRST_REASON_ID = B.REASON_ID)
 FROM BUSN_INFO A
WHERE a.last_reason_id IS NOT NULL
   OR a.first_reason_id IS NOT NULL
```

This assumes that a row that doesn't have one of the two has a `NULL` value stored rather than some other identifier that you want to interpret as "missing".

If you're using joins instead, you'd want to do outer joins instead and add the same `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT i.busn_id,
       i.area_name,
       i.date,
       i.area_status,
       i.last_reason_id,
       last_reason.reason_description,
       i.first_reason_id,
       first_reason.reason_description
  FROM busn_info i
       LEFT JOIN busn_reason first_reason
         ON( i.first_reason_id = first_reason.reason_id )
       LEFT JOIN busn_reason last_reason
         ON( i.last_reason_id = last_reason.reason_id )
  WHERE i.last_reason_id IS NOT NULL
     OR i.first_reason_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, I used inner joins not an inline. I posted an update query.

Comment: I want rows where First_Reason_ID and LAST_REASON_ID are both in the table, where FIRST_REASON_ID is and last isn't, and where LAST_REASON_ID is and first isn't

Comment: @ITNovice15 - See my update.  You'd want to do a couple of outer joins in that case.

Comment: So I have a trunc(sysdate) in my where clause (getting a month of data). Would I use AND WHERE i.last_reason_id IS NOT NULL
     OR i.first_reason_id IS NOT NULL?

Comment: Also, would I not use first_reason at all? I'd only use the i table?

Comment: @ITNovice15 - If you have other predicates already, you probably want to use parenthesis to group the predicates-- `where <<predicate 1>> and (i.last_reason_id is not null or i.first_reason_id is not null)`-- rather than ensuring that you and everyone that ever maintains this code remembers the order of operations.  You could use predicates on both `first_reason` and `last_reason` instead but that would generally be more complicated.

Comment: Yep - the parenthesis were what I was missing. Thanks again, Justin!

Answer (score 0):

If you need at least one of them to be not null,
then add:

```
WHERE a.last_reason_id IS NOT NULL OR a.first_reason_id IS NOT NULL
```

If you also need to exclude rows where both values are specified, then use

```
WHERE a.last_reason_id IS NOT NULL AND a.first_reason_id IS NULL  
   OR a.first_reason_id IS NOT NULL AND a.last_reason_id IS NULL
```

or

```
WHERE NOT (a.last_reason_id IS NULL and a.first_reason_id IS NULL)
  AND NOT (a.last_reason_id IS NOT NULL and a.first_reason_id IS NOT NULL)
```

both variants produce the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong query I used. I'm using inner joins. How would this change for that?

Comment: Just add "Left" before join - this will allow these columns to be null

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT busn_id,
       area_name,
       date,
       area_status,
       a.last_reason_id,
       a.first_reason_id,
from   busn_info a
       (
              SELECT reason_description,
                     reason_id
              FROM   busn_reasons ) b
ON a.reason_id=b.reason_id
       (
              SELECT b.reason_description
              FROM   busn_reasons b
              WHERE  a.first_reason_id = b.reason_id )
```

Comment: Please read informations about formatting in Help Center: [How do I format my posts...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).